# Aframe asset unload

Tags: three.js, aframe

I have created an aframe animation where lots of external png files are loaded in a sequence. Works like a charm on desktop, crashes smartphones with little RAM.

Is there anything like an "asset unload" in aframe such as in three.js?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

In 0.2.0, you have to do:

```
AFRAME.utils.texture.textureCache[yourimagesrc]['1 1'].then(function (texture) { texture.dispose(); });
```

In master (upcoming 0.3.0), you have to do:

```
document.querySelector('a-scene').systems.material.textureCache[yourimagesrc]['1 1'].then(function (texture) { texture.dsipose(); });
```

I had some work doing automatic texture disposal when no longer used. I hope to reintroduce it in 0.4.0. For now, blame current mobile browsers as being ill-suited for VR.

Comment: Just a note, calling `dispose()` on the texture didn't work for me, and neither did removing the texture object from `AFRAME.utils.texture.textureCache` on 0.2.0