# Freeing memory / clearing cache after videosphere stops

Tags: aframe

Is there a way to manually deallocate memory or clear cache after a videosphere is done playing? I'm using A-Frame on iOS with Cordova for a video project (not ideal tech combo, but my hands are tied there), but after a few videos the app crashes on attempting to play the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Try digging into the texture cache and disposing it: [Aframe asset unload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520628/aframe-asset-unload)

May or may not work.

Comment: I got the texture.dispose() working for videos like this:

    `AFRAME.utils.texture.textureCache['video-id'].then (function (texture) {
        texture.dispose ();
    });`

For videos loaded in `<a-assets>`, the textureCache key is the video ID minus the #.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be fixing the memory issues because the app still crashes as soon as you call play after a few videos have played through.